# WCF Named Pipes within WPF application

Tags: .net, wpf, wcf, named-pipes

How would you run a WCF named pipe service in the background of a WPF Windows application?  I can't seem to find any samples of running the WCF server within a WPF application.

Any ideas?

I am currently using the following code in the Application_Startup.  Does this need to run with it's own thread?

```
    Using Host As ServiceModel.ServiceHost = New ServiceModel.ServiceHost(GetType(Service), New Uri(("net.pipe://localhost")))
        '
        Host.AddServiceEndpoint(GetType(IService), New ServiceModel.NetNamedPipeBinding, "Test")
        Host.Open()
        '
    End Using
```

Comment: It may or may not apply, but a recent SO question about the same in a WinForms application found he needed to start the ServiceHost in a thread other than the UI thread. Also, please update your question to say what problem you're having. Exception? Can't connect? What?

Comment: You probably found this out already, but for the benefit of others, yes I would recommend running in its own thread.  I did a similar server running in Winforms and if you don't run in a separate thread, anything untoward happening runs the risk of locking up the GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the Using code block and setup the ServiceHost as a private variable within the WPF Application class. I then close the ServiceHost when the application exits. Seems to work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Juval Lowy provides helper classes in his ServiceModelEx library along with information on how to run WCF components in-process, which is probably what you're going to want to do with your WCF component since you want to use named-pipes which requires the component to be running on the same machine as your WPF app.

I suggest reading about the InProcFactory class starting on page 60 of the 2nd Edition of "[Programming WCF Services](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596521301/)" by Juval Lowy.  This is essentially the "bible" of WCF.

This will show you exactly how to host your component in process using his helper classes.

Comment: Starting the ServiceHost within the WPF Application class seem to fix the issue.  Thanks for the book recommendation!

Comment: Could you please answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9702379/queuing-in-oneway-wcf-messages-using-windows-service-and-sql-server ?